# Invalid path for Android NDK in Eclipse Preferences

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I'm looking to incorporate the NDK for C++ code use in my Android project. I'm using Eclipse Android IDE and I've just downloaded android-ndk-r9-darwin-x86_64.tar.bz2 for OSX 64bit. I've uncompressed the ndk and have it in my home folder, but when I attempt to setup the path inside Eclipse prefs, I get this error

[image: Invalid path for NDK]

I've looked at this similar question ([Eclipse error: invalid path for ndk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936637/eclipse-error-invalid-path-for-ndk)) for answers, but every suggestion didn't solve the problem. Other relevant information, I have Make 3.8.1, up-to-date SDK, Sequoyah.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936637/eclipse-error-invalid-path-for-ndk

Comment: Right, I said in my question I already looked at that question and every suggestion didn't solve the problem.

Comment: does the path holds the scripts nkd-Build ... ?

Comment: hey user24, yeah ndk-build is inside the directory at the path

Comment: Hey.. check if both sdk and ndk are in the same drive say C: etc,if not try to keep them in one drive and check.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and documented the solution to this problem. It are the first 2 steps of the next link you'll need:
http://aplacetogeek.wordpress.com/android-with-opencl-tutorial/

Edit:

**The solution is this:**

**Step 1: setup Android NDK**

1. Download the NDK from:
   http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html
2. I unzipped it in the adt-bundle but you can unzip it anywhere you
   want. 
   *Note or remember the path you used. I'll need it in the next steps!*
3. Go to Window -> Preferences -> Android -> NDK
4. Browse to android-ndk-r9c.
   *Example:* `/home/dries/AndroidDev/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/android-ndk-r9c`
5. Click apply and ok

**Step 2: configure Android NDK for your project**

1. Right click on your project folder. Choose android tools -> add
   native support **(! the bottom one !)** and click finish.
2. The file you just created is going to be your own .so file. This
   will be your personal library with the functions you create yourself
   in the JNI folder.
3. Now you should see a JNI folder in your project with a .cpp and an
   Android.mk file in it.
4. Go to project -> properties -> C/C++ build -> build variables -> add

   > Name: NDKROOT
   >
   > Value: your android-ndk-r9c folder you also added to NDK in step 1.
5. Click Ok
6. Go to C/C++ build and uncheck Use default build path. 
   Change the
   build path to `${NDKROOT}/ndk-build`. Make sure you did not end the NDKROOT value on / !
7. Click apply

You should be able to use the NDK now and compile without errors.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: Thank you for the tips! You are right, answers on stackoverflow are better manageable than other websites. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Found a work-around solution to my question with the help from this forum: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/YPFPa9Fen7Y

I downloaded an old copy of the NDK (r5b) and there were no errors when setting up the path, as opposed to r9 the most recent version. As the forum says, the problem lies with Sequoyah which has not updated since 2011 and can not recognize the new structure of that the NDK is laid out in. Hope this helps someone in the future. (If you find a direct solution though, let me know.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of downloading another version of the NDK, I simply created links inside the `build` folder to the `toolchains`, `prebuilt` and `platforms` which recreates the folder hierarchy of the r4 NDK.

Doing this made the plugin happy, and I only have one version of the NDK on my computer.